# VBA only catches the first 2 columns of a query but there are 4 columns

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

Im making a DB in Microsoft Access where i need to use a query to make a combo box with some names of products and services
This is the query:

```sql
SELECT [Product Name] AS Name, 'Products' AS Type, Description AS Description, 
Price AS [Unit Price] FROM Products
UNION ALL
SELECT [Service Name] AS Name, 'Services' AS Type, Description AS Description, 
[Unit Price] FROM Services;
```

After that, i need the data from the description and the unit price from the query when i select an option from the combo box, but when i use this VBA to autofill the description on a form, it returns null values for the description and the unit price, but "Name" and "Type" are catched and printed on the console succesfully

```
Private Sub Item_Click()
    Dim selectedItem As String
    Dim selectedDescription As String
    
    Debug.Print Me.Item.Column(0) ' Print the name
    Debug.Print Me.Item.Column(1) ' Print the type
    Debug.Print Me.Item.Column(2) ' Print the description
    Debug.Print Me.Item.Column(3) ' Print the price
    
    selectedItem = Me.Item.Value
    selectedDescription = Me.Item.Column(2)

    If Not IsNull(selectedDescription) Then
        Me.Description.Value = selectedDescription
    Else
        Me.Description.Value = "Description not available"
    End If
End Sub
```

I've already tried changing the names of the variables, use the code in another form, filled the few blank spaces were there, change the index of the columns and changing the controls of the original form :(
Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: I cannot replicate issue. Suggest you post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analyis.

Comment: Also, `If Not IsNull(selectedDescription)` will always be True as you have Dim'ed it as String.

Comment: When I run the VBA code, the debugger highlights the line where it recovers the data, so  the "If Not IsNull(selectedDescription)" never runs

Comment: Exactly which line is highlighted and what is error message? Edit your question. A declared String variable can never be Null, so use: `If selectedDescription <> "" Then`

Answer (score 1):

Access ComboBoxes have a `Column Count` property (in the Format tab of the property sheet).

This property has a value of 2 according to your description. Increase it to 4.

Note: if you don't want to display all of these properties, you can set their column widths to 0.

E.g. Column Widths: `3cm;4cm;0cm;0cm` (the separator may vary according to your Windows settings).

---

There is also a problem with your query. `Description AS Description` creates a circular reference. Either just write `Description` or write `Products.Description AS Description`. But there is no point specifying an alias if the column name is the desired name.

Also, the aliases given in the second SELECT command are ignored.

A text column can be either NULL or an empty string `""`; however, a `String` variable cannot be `NULL` in VBA. It can only be `""`.

Therefore, we have to compare with

```vb
If selectedDescription <> "" Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: I did it but it gives me the same result, also, when i did it, the combo box values dissapeard

Comment: "the combo box values disappeared" ??? I cannot reproduce this. Disappeared from what? This code does not delete the combo box.

Comment: The Nz() is meaningless because a declared String variable cannot be Null. However, could be useful if applied to a field which can hold Null. I tested ColumnCount - didn't matter what it was set to, I could still reference all columns and get values in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I tried instead of using directly de query description and price data, i used DLookup with the type the query recovered and directly catch the original data from both of the table

```vb
Private Sub Item_Click()
    Dim selectedItem As String
    Dim selectedDescription As String
    Dim tableName As String
    
    selectedItem = Me.Item.Value
    Debug.Print selectedItem
    Debug.Print Me.Item.Column(1)
    
    If selectedItem <> "" Then
        If Me.Item.Column(1) = "Productos" Then
            tableName = "Productos"
            Debug.Print tableName
            selectedDescription = DLookup("Descripción", tableName, "[Nombre del producto] = '" & selectedItem & "'")
            
        Else
            tableName = "Servicios"
            Debug.Print tableName
            selectedDescription = DLookup("Descripción", tableName, "[Nombre del servicio] = '" & selectedItem & "'")
        End If
        
        Me.[Descripción].Value = selectedDescription
    End If
End Sub
```

It's a temporal solution but now it works, thanks for your help :)